# Group Size not Matching Column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```r
Observations: 49,358
Variables: 22
$ congress                      <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ icpsr                         <int> 99869, 4766, 845...
```

The congress variable goes from 1 till 116. I am trying to create a variable that identifies that start of congress (1789) and goes on till the end (2019) in 2 year intervals. This variable would have length 116, equal to the group size of congress. Yet, when I run the following code:

```r
data %>%
group_by(congress) %>%
mutate(start = seq(1789,2019,2))
```

I get this error:

```r
Error: Column `start` must be length 96 (the group size) or one, not 116
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the next verison of `dplyr` (`1.0.0`) the attempted code would work as it is with `summarise` but in the meantime, you could get data in a list and `unnest` :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(congress) %>%
  summarise(start = list(seq(1789,2019,2))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(start)
```

Comment: the code works, but I lose my other variables in the dataset

Comment: @HAK Do all the other variables have the same size (116) for each `congress`? How do you want to store them?

Comment: @rohan-shah no, they have the same size as the ungrouped dataset 49358 obs. I would want the other observations as is after I ungroup the dataset.

Comment: `seq(1789,2019,2)` is of length 196, you need every group of the same size to keep all columns. Another option is to just duplicate records across each row `data %>%
  mutate(start = list(seq(1789,2019,2)))`